# How to iterate over GQLQuery objects when an attribute exists for only some of them

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

So I'm building a basic blog where I've also implemented an IP address API to store the user's location. I've used [this website](http://ip-api.com)'s API to get the latitude and longitude of the user. This is the `Entries` class which is used to store each entry -

```
class Entries(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    body = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    coords = db.GeoPtProperty()
```

This is the function to store the latitude and longitude in the `coords` property -

```
IP_URL = 'http://ip-api.com/xml/'
def get_coords(ip):
    ip = '4.2.2.2'
    url = IP_URL + ip
    content = None
    try:
        content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    except urllib2.URLError:
        return
    if content:
        # parse the XML and find the coordinates
        dom = minidom.parseString(content)
        status = dom.getElementsByTagName("status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        if status == 'success':
            lonNode = dom.getElementsByTagName('lon')[0]
            latNode = dom.getElementsByTagName('lat')[0]
            if lonNode and latNode and lonNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue and latNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue:
                lon = lonNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue
                lat = latNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue
                return db.GeoPt(lat, lon)
```

When I go to the admin page (`localhost:8000`), I can see that some entries have the `coords` property while others don't. (To be precise, I have 8 entries currently, 6 of which have nothing in the `coords` column, 1 has the coordinates of `4.2.2.2` and the other has `None`, because I had passed in my `localhost` address.)

I have a main page where I list all the entries in the blog and it's here that I tried to see whether I can actually get all the coordinates stored in the database, to be displayed on the page -

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # self.response.write(self.request.remote_addr)
        # self.response.write(repr(get_coords(self.request.remote_addr)))
        entries = db.GqlQuery('select * from Entries order by created desc limit 10')
        # find which entries have coordinates
        points = []
        for e in entries:
            if entries.coords:
                points.append(a.coords)

        self.response.write(repr(points))
        self.response.write(render_str('mainpage.html', entries=entries))
```

I tried printing out the property itself - `self.response.write(repr(get_coords(self.request.remote_addr)))` and it showed `datastore_types.GeoPt(40.7128, -74.0059)`. So it seems the property IS stored in Datastore.

The problem I have is that the interpreter throws an `AttributeError` for the loop in the `get` of `MainPage()`-

```
AttributeError: 'GqlQuery' object has no attribute 'coords'
```

I think this may be because some of the entries do not have a `coords` attribute in the first place. But if this is the case, is there any way around it?

If it's of any use, I'm doing this for the Web Development course on Udacity by Steve Huffman and he showed this method of storing and displaying the user coordinates. He instructed to NOT use `required=True` for the `coords` property as the already existing entries don't have that property. When he looped over the entries in his blog, everything seemed fine and all the coordinates were displayed as a `list`.

Comment: Since this was caused by a typo, might as well delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

I used a `filter` instead of the `for` loop inside `MainPage`.

```
points = filter(None, (e.coords for e in entries))
```

This seemed to work and displayed the list of coordinates. (Though I still do not understand why this method worked)

Edit: I found out why I got the problem with my original code. It should have been `e.coords`, rather than `entries.coords`.